# Recognize a user as Customer after authenticating from custom form Magento2

Tags: magento, authentication, magento2

I don't know if you get the idea from the tittle but here's the explanation. Im a newbie on magento so not so familiar with the whole complex structure it has.

I added another form on the login and register page, so that the users can register and authenticate themselves using the form i added, say it reads data from some external device. I'm all done with the option of registering the user, also the data retrieving and matching when authenticating.

But when it comes to authenticate the user, how do i get Magento2 to recognize him/her as a Customer? I need to add the recognizing part, where after authenticating the user is given Customer permission even though their data is saved on a complete new table of the database and isn't the same data provided as the usual form of registering and authenticating.

Comment: nobody is replying.. is this (what i am asking) even possible?

Comment: You should save your custom registration form data in customers table. `EXAMPLE: You have to create new customer manually while you registers from your external registration page`

Comment: You should use this while you register the customer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78164/how-to-add-a-customer-programmatically-in-magento-2